# QTreeWidget dropped item gets deleted when using setDropAction

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidget

I am trying to make a `QTreeWidget` that lets the user rearrange its elements, and if the user drags and drops a tree item to another widget I don't want the item to be deleted. To get this behavior, I'm trying to use `setDropAction` in `dropEvent`.

The code below successfully rejects drops from other widgets, and allows drops to other widgets without deleting the original, but it seems to break drag-and-drop within the tree - it causes the item to disappear when dropped.

https://www.screencast.com/t/driIjyg8ekzt

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MyTree(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setDragDropMode(self.DragDrop)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(self.SelectRows)
        self.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dropEvent(self, e: QtGui.QDropEvent):
        if e.source() is self:
            print("move")
            e.setDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
            e.accept()
        super().dropEvent(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    my_list = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
    my_list.addItems(list('1234'))
    my_list.show()
    my_list.setDragEnabled(True)
    my_list.setAcceptDrops(True)

    my_tree = MyTree()
    for item in list('abcd'):
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(my_tree, [item])
    my_tree.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to prevent drop from external sources, just use:

```
    self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
```

And don't reimplement `dropEvent()`.

Your code doesn't work properly mostly because you've set the event as accepted, and an item view ignores a drop event if it has already been accepted.

In your case, it would be better to do this:

```
    def dzropEvent(self, e: QtGui.QDropEvent):
        if e.source() != self:
            # ignore the drop from other sources
            return
        e.setDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        super().dropEvent(e)
```

But if you really want to ignore external drops, you should ignore the event right from the `dragEnterEvent()`, so that it's made also clear to the user that dropping is not allowed.